# How to install seleniumHQ for Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation

I would like to know how to install SeleniumHQ (http://seleniumhq.org/download/) on Windows XP/Vista/7?

On Ubuntu/Debian system you need to just type those commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip xvfb xserver-xephyr
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

and then I can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import selenium
# ...
```

but how about Windows?

I finally did it but not at all. I just installed seleniumHQ:

```
1. Download the last pip version from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads
2. Uncompress it
3. Download the last easy installer for Windows: (download the .exe at the bottom of http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools ). Install it.
4. Go to the uncompressed pip directory and: python setup.py install
5. Add your python c:\Python2x\Scripts to the path
6. Run cmd.exe and type: pip install -U selenium
```

and I can finally type:

```
python
>> from selenium import selenium
>>
```

and it works, yay! But still have problems with installing this:

```
xvfb xserver-xephyr
```

On Ubuntu/Debian OS I just need to type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip xvfb xserver-xephyr
```

and it works but how about Windows? I asked on superuser.com ([take a look](https://superuser.com/questions/479397/how-to-install-seleniumhq-for-python-on-windows)) but nobody replied :(

Comment: Have you seen http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#detailed-instructions-for-windows-users ?

Comment: @Pengman: yup, I saw this but still have problems with installing http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html ... I know I have to install this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe/download but what else do I need? I mean, how to install virtualenv?

Comment: I cant remember if you need anything else, sorry.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/), a wrapper to selenium which makes some thinks easier. It can be installed with `pip install splinter`.

Comment: @brandizzi: OMG I love you :D It works on Windows (at least Windows XP) thank you so much!